# Need help in Solidworks Macros. I want to add 5mm into previous dimension

Tags: solidworks, cad

Basically I have nearly 1000 files. I want to edit a dimension which is labeled D2@Sketch 10. Assuming that the name can be a variable, I want to do this task:

D2@Sketch 10 = D2@Sketch 10 + 0.005

So basically I want to take the value of the dimension, add 5mm to it and then assign it to itself. To put simply, add 5mm in an already existing value of dimension.

I am sure that there is no other way I can achieve my goal in batch processing these files.

I have very little experience with Macros. I am attaching the part file and the macro I have used previously to assign specific values to dimensions.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19SiwRlHFebL4Ma_cUFh2RAG2NP9lk_y8?usp=sharing

Comment: SolidWorks Macro Record will capture steps you complete manually. Then you can manually make changes.

Comment: But I am not able to add the logic of adding just 5mm to a dimension. It gets passed as the value that I give in the recording session.

By someway, I should be able to call the previous dimension value and then add 5mm to it.

Answer (score 0):

This line works OK for me

Part.Parameter("D1@Sketch10").SystemValue = Part.Parameter("D1@Sketch10").SystemValue + 0.005